# How to uninstall overridden system module in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I accidentally installed a drupal update (6.26) **into sites/all/modules** (**yes**, I put there the whole drupal root directory, so I have `sites/all/modules/modules`, `sites/all/modules/sites/all/modules`, etc).

Then, unknowingly ran update.php, and everything went ok as Drupal intelligently registered the new core modules in `sites/all/modules/modules/*` as core modules.

This worked fine until the next update. I placed the core drupal files into the root dir, and the core was correctly replaced with 6.27. But in `sites/all/modules` were the 6.26 files from the last update and drupal accepts OLDER files in `sites/all/modules` that **override** the core `/modules` files.

So drupal now complained that it was still at 6.26, even when the real core was at 6.27 - those files were never actually called, because overridden by `/sites/all/modules/modules/*`.

So:
I managed to remove all the unneeded modules from there and with a few errors, I got it working again. the best method was:
changing the `sites/all/modules/modules/<module>/<module>.info` file and tweaking the version number from 6.27 to something older, like 6.25. **THEN** run update.php - so Drupal recognizes that there is an OLDER version in sites/all/modules than in core. now remove the directory and run update.php again. Now everything is clean for this module.

But this does not work for the **system** module. Each time I try to remove the `sites/all/modules/modules/system/` directory, the update.php URL is not callable any more (HTTP Error 500).

Any hints how to recover from an accidentally overridden system module?

Comment: Do you have a backup before the update? And don't complicate your life with such a nested folder structure.

Comment: ah, no backup (shame on me.) - Complicated folder structure? It's the original drupal structure... The only change was the accidentally "root update" **into** the /sites/all/modules dir, so I had accidentally a whole drupal subsystem in /sites/all/modules.

Comment: yeah, I was referring about the a full drupal under `sites/all/modules` directory. what happens if you remove that and basically have a, among friends, a normal version?

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question (or I didn't understand your answer...). I **accidentally** copied that drupal suite into `sites/all/modules`. I certainly removed it again, but when removing the last module `system`, drupal doesn't find the real `system` module and is broken.

Comment: It looks like your `{system}` table is broken. Can you run this query and paste the result: `SELECT filename FROM {system} WHERE name = 'system'`?  If the path  is not something like this: `modules/system/system.module` then at least we know where the problem is.

Comment: there is no result. I can give you a full result of `select filename from system`: http://pastebin.com/NqHZj7D5 - this are the full filename field rows of the system table. There is no "system" in there... Does that help

Comment: Yes it does, it seems that your `{system}' table is broken. You're missing at least 2 important lines: `modules/system/system.module` and `modules/user/user.module`. Do you have Drush installed?

Comment: You should look into this: [Registry Rebuild](http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild), they mention your exact problem that the system table is broken.

Comment: hm yes, there is just the `sites/all/modules/modules/system/system.module` path and same with `user`. What I did is rename this string into the right one (`modules/user/user.module`) - but it didn't help. - And the Registry Rebuild module is D7 only, think this does not help me.

Comment: OH - SORRY: It says _"The drush version now also fixes Drupal 6 sites where modules have been moved around or removed and the system table is broken."_ So it's D6 too, but only the Drush one - and I don't have Drush there on that server - it's a hosted one. I could only copy it on my local test web server, fix it with drush and copy the db back again online. Would that be a way to go?

Comment: Funny. the way there did not work. the script crashed. But I solved the problem: I just renamed `sites/all/modules/modules/system/system.module` into `modules/system/system.module` in the system table. Then I deleted the wrong `sites/all/modules/modules/system` directory. Then ran update.php. Now everything is ok again ;-) Thanks all.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked! You should post your solution as an answer. Some people might also ran into the same issue but don't have the time to read through all the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer (Thanks to Max), and want to share it in case of other people suffer from the same problem.

This solution should work if you accidentally installed a drupal update into a subdirectory like `/sites/all/modules`.
After running update.php, the system db table gets updated to the new paths, so all modules that are **not** in `/modules` have priority over the ones in `/modules`. You can deinstall all optional modules, so that they get purged from the system table as well with no problem.

In case of the `system` module, this is not simply possible, as you cannot *deinstall* the `system` module, when a wrong one is installed.

So what you have to do is:

1. Open the `system` table with e.g. phpMyAdmin, and search for the system module: `SELECT * FROM system WHERE name = "system"`.
2. change the `filename` field from "sites/all/modules/modules/system/system.module" (or whatever there is) into "modules/system/system.module"
3. Now (and this is important **before** you run *update.php*!) delete the wrong system module folder.
4. Run *update.php*

Now Drupal should find the original (built in) system module - everything should be ok.